# Java library for reading geojson from MySQL

Tags: geojson, java, mysql, well-known-text

I am looking for a way to retrieve `mysql` `geometry` data as `geojson` from the database either using a `java` library or for converting `wkt` to `geojson` using either `java` or `javascript`.

Currently I am doing a lot of string manipulation and regular expression matching to accomplish this.I am using the `Google Maps V3 Javascript API` as the mapping solution.

My setup is very simple,I use `Java Servlets` to load JSP pages and recieve AJAX requests.
I write and read data from a column of type `geometry` using a `mysql` database using `InnoDB` as my mapping engine.I am using the `mysql-connector` to insert/query data from the `database` using `Java`.I use the `Data` layer on `Google Maps v3 Javascript API` to render data as `geojson`.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: This question is far too broad in its current state. You need to give us more details about your data, and what you have tried so far. If you have just points, it should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, GeoJSON support is one of the new features in MySQL 5.7.5, which is to be released soon I think. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-5.html for more information.